# Contar Numeros introducidos en un Scanner

Tags: java

Quiero hacer un programa en Java que lea una línea de la entrada standard utilizando la clase `Scanner`.

El usuario escribirá una línea con números separados por espacios; por ejemplo :

```
3 10 0 13 4
```

El programa debe contar cuántos números han sido introducidos en la línea. Y procesar esos números en un bucle para imprimir cuales son pares y cuales impares.

La salida para el ejemplo anterior sería :

```
3 es IMPAR
10 es PAR
0 es PAR
13 es IMPAR
4 es PAR
SE VERIFICO  : 5  NÚMEROS
```

He probado a leer los números con el siguiente programa pero el problema es que no se sale del bucle while cuando el usuario pulsa INTRO para indicar fin de línea. Este es el programa que no funciona :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numerosLeidos = 0;
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int numero = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Se ha introducido el numero : " + numero);
    ++numero;
  }
  System.out.println("Se han leido : " + numerosLeidos ); // Nunca se llega a esta linea
}
```

Comment: No soy el *downvoter*. La [entrada estándar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), `System.in`, no tiene [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) por *diseño*... De manera que `Scanner` siempre espera una entrada, puesto que aún no ha recibido la seña de final de archivo. Mi recomendación es que leas línea por línea. En cada línea, procesa los datos introducidos con, si quieres, otra instancia de `Scanner`.

Comment: Jaime, me he tomado la libertad de editar completamente tu pregunta. Creo que he respetado la esencia de lo que preguntas. Con una pregunta formulada así hubiese sido más fácil y rápido solventar tu duda. Pero si consideras que mi edición no respeta tu pregunta original no dudes en revertirla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontre la solucion! y por mi mismo!

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int input=1;
String inputtexto= "0";
int cont=0;

inputtexto = scanner.nextLine(); 
String[] numberstexto = inputtexto.split(" ");
cont=numberstexto.length;
int numbers [] = new int [cont];

for(int o=0;o<cont;o++){
    numbers [o] = Integer.parseInt(numberstexto[o]);
    System.out.println(numbers [o]);
}

for(int i=0;i<cont;i++){
    if((numbers[i])%2 ==0)System.out.println(numbers[i]+" es PAR" );
    else System.out.println(numbers[i]+" es IMPAR");
}

System.out.println("SE VERIFICO  : " +cont +"  NÚMEROS");
```

Comment: Iba a editar mi respuesta para poner una solución también basada en `String.split`, pero veo que has tenido la misma idea, muy bien hecho. Una pequeña mejora sería usar `"\s+"` en el split en vez de `" "`, así el programa funciona aunque haya más de un espacio entre los números. +1 para ti; y no olvides que puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Es bueno que encuentres solución tú mismo aunque mi respuesta hace lo mismo :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        int cont=0; //si desea contar cuantos numeros ingreso 
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {//solicita una nueva entrada
          int val  =scanner.nextInt(); 
          if(val%2 ==0)System.out.println(val+" PAR" );
          else System.out.println(val+ " IMPAR");
          cont++;
       }
    System.out.println("SE VERIFICO  : " +cont +"  NÚMEROS");
```

Comment: Hola @DevJoel. Gracias por contribuir. Quizás convendría agregar un pequeño comentario sobre cómo el código responde a la pregunta, para beneficiar a futuros lectores.

Comment: Gracias, el problema es que el programa termina porque escribo exit, yo nesecito que termine automaticamente despues que ya no hay mas scanner.hasNext

Comment: Entonces tendría que leer una sola cadena con las entradas separadas por espacios por ejemplo `12 15 16` si no desea usar espacios podría usar delimitadores

Answer (score -1):

No tienes que hacer nada en tu código Java para que `Scanner.hasNext()` llegue a tener el valor `false`.

Sencillamente tienes que escribir un EOF (End Of File = Fin De Fichero) y `Scanner.hasNext()` devolverá `false`.

En Linux si ejecutas desde una consola la forma de escribir un EOF es pulsando CTRL+D

Prueba este programa :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerFin {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
      String cadena = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Cadena leida = " + cadena);
    }
    System.out.println("Fin del programa");
  }
}
```

Compílalo, ejecútalo, escribe unas líneas y pulsa CTRL+D :

> jose2@HP-Negro:~$ javac ScannerFin.java
>   jose2@HP-Negro:~$ java ScannerFin
>   hola
>   Cadena leida = hola
>   veintisiete
>   Cadena leida = veintisiete

Aquí pulso CTRL+D

> Fin del programa
>   jose2@HP-Negro:~$

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es:
preguntar al usuario varios numeros, luego decirle cual es inpar y cual es par, y quiero que el pueda poner infinidad de numeros (sin que el termine el programa como el caso que me pusiste)

Comment: Claro que sí. Usa una variable inicializada a 0 e increméntala cada vez que se introduce un número.

Comment: edite el comentario

Comment: como hago eso?, yo no puedo saber cuantos numeros introdujo en un scanner

Comment: Supongamos que el usuario introduce 7 números. ¿Qué quieres que haga el programa tras leer esos 7 números? ----- Te sugiero que intentes un programa similar al de esta pregunta pero con nextInt en vez de nextLine. Y como los comentarios no son para conversaciones extendidas, [usa este chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45292/usandoscanner), es ahí donde te seguiré respondiendo, no por comentarios.